# Time Complexity of complex nested for loops

Tags: python, for-loop, time-complexity

what are the time complexities of the following code?

```
def func(n):
    for _ in range(n):
        if n == 4:
            for _ in range(n):
                <do something>
```

It will only be O(n^2) for one specific input (n = 4) but is O(n) for all other inputs.  In this case the worst case is obviously O(n^2), yet my instructor says that O(n) is the correct answer.  If "big-Oh" notation is to indicate the worst case scenario, why is it not O(n^2)?

Another one is:

```
def func2(n):
    for _ in range(n):
        if n%2 == 0:
            for _ in range(n):
                <do something>
```

I am not so certain about the run time of this piece of code.  Again, worst case is O(n^2).  This time half of all possible inputs results in the worst case.  Would this suffice in saying that the code runs in O(n^2) time?

If the first part is O(n) and the second part is O(n^2), is there a general rule of thumb when you choose the truly worst case for the "big-Oh" representation?

Comment: O-notation ignores a finite number of "small" values of n. For *n > 4* the first function only does *n* iterations per function call, so the asymptotic complexity is O(n). The second function is indeed O(n^2). The general method is to find a closed form for the number of instructions depending on *n* and then figure out big-Oh from there

Comment: As per [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation): In mathematics, big O notation describes the limiting behavior of a function when the argument tends towards a particular value or infinity, usually in terms of simpler functions.  So as n grows towards infinity complexity is O(n).

Comment: What if `<do something>` is .. factor `ackermann(n, n)`

Comment: This question appears to be topical for http://cs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Kaz, thanks for the link.  I did not know about that.  By the way, that is precisely what I had in mind for <do something> :)

Comment: Worst case means "worst possible input *of a particular size*". It's not particularly applicable in case 1.

Comment: No matter what `<do something>` is, if it halts, then it must do so in a finite amount of time, and you can find an input such that iterating over `range(n)` will take longer than that amount of time (assuming you have enough memory).

Comment: Big-O does refer to the worst possible case. But n=4 is not the worst possible case. In fact for n=4 `func1` will run very quickly.

Answer (score 0):

updated

The first case is O(n) since even when n=4, the complexity is a nested loop with range 4 which has constant expense of 16 iterations. For all other values of n, it is O(n). As n grows, the condition where n==4 is never achieved, so the complexity does not grow with n.

In case 2, half the calls to func2 involve an inner loop with complexity O(n^2) which is why the overall complexity is O(n^2). As n grows, the time requirements grow O(n^2)

Comment: Hi, I may be wrong but I don't think your answer is correct.  The if cases say if n == 4 or if n%2 == 0.  To me that means that the if the input value (n) is 4 or even then the second for loop will execute.